# How to create a new file containing an image from drawable in android?

Tags: android, image-viewer, create-view

I need pick an image from Drawable directory.
My code is :

```
private  void CreateViewForIndex(View rootView, int index) {
    // Instantiate GPUImageView object          
    ImageView mGPUImageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image); 

    // Set an image from file inside GPUImageView object    
    File imageFile = new File("/MainActivity/res/drawable-hdpi/russia.jpeg");               
    mImageView.setImage(imageFile);

    // Apply filter
    mImageView.setFilter(returnFilterForIndex(index));
}
```

Where rootView is the View. I need to create a new `File` object from an image in the following directory: `/MainActivity/res/drawable-hdpi/russia.jpeg`. The problem is that I am unable to get the right directory for the previous image file so the jpeg is never displayed.

Comment: use mImageView.setImageRessource(R.drawable.russia)

Comment: Ty, but i'm using a GPUImageView library, then i cant use a setImageResource, i can use setBackgroundResource,but i dont want this method.
How can i doing ?

Comment: have you get solution for this ? please help me i just want the same .

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to create file from drawable resource as-is without any additional encoding-decoding involved in the process. In this code file is saved into application private cache, but this can be easily modified to accommodate saving to any file.

```
public File createFileFromResource(int resId, String fileName)
{
    File f;
    try
    {
        f = new File(getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        out.close();
        is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        f = null;
    }
    return f;
}
```

You can use above method like this:

```
private void CreateViewForIndex(View rootView, int index) 
{
    // Instantiate GPUImageView object          
    GPUImageView mGPUImageView = GPUImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image); 

    // Set an image from file inside GPUImageView object    
    File imageFile = new File(R.drawable.russia, "russia.jpeg"); 
    if (imageFile != null) 
    {           
        mImageView.setImage(imageFile);    
        // Apply filter
        mImageView.setFilter(returnFilterForIndex(index));
    }
}
```

---

When you are no longer using created cache file it would be good to delete it in order to minimize your app storage use with

```
imageFile.delete();
```

or you can clean all cached files on app exit with

```
public void deleteInternalCacheFiles()
{
    File[] cacheFiles = getCacheDir().listFiles();
    for (File file : cacheFiles)
    {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

However, if you cache only small number of files and/or those files do not occupy too much memory, you can safely skip that part.